# null pointer exception with authentication form on Glassfish 5.1

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, glassfish

Following the official documentation, I have a very simple JEE login form which is working fine in local Glassfish 5.1 development machine.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkbaa.html

However, when deployed on a production in a cluster instance, same 5.1 version, when hitting any page that requires authentication I am getting the following stack trace.
The realm is a regular "file" realm.

```
  Unexpected error forwarding or redirecting to login page
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.logging.LogCleanerUtil.neutralizeForLog(LogCleanerUtil.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.<init>(ApplicationDispatcher.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.getRequestDispatcher(StandardContext.java:7382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getRequestDispatcher(ApplicationContext.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getRequestDispatcher(ApplicationContextFacade.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.forwardToLoginPage(FormAuthenticator.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:222)
    at com.sun.web.security.RealmAdapter.invokeAuthenticateDelegate(RealmAdapter.java:1515)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:579)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

I have inspected the [LogCleanerUtil](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/blob/master/nucleus/common/common-util/src/main/java/com/sun/logging/LogCleanerUtil.java) class, which is supposed to be open source.

```
public static String neutralizeForLog(String message){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int offset  = 0; offset < message.length(); ){
        final int point = message.codePointAt(offset);
        if(Character.isValidCodePoint(point)){
            sb.append(encodeCharacter(point));
        }
        offset += Character.charCount(point);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The null pointer is happening because of `message` being null.
The question is why message is null ? Are we talking about a log message right ? Apart from the OS version, the only difference with the local environment is that on prod server I have created the glassfish realm and the whole cluster with asadmin command.

Here is the web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Admin Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/console/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <description>Console Admin</description>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>console-realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well...after a little investigation it turns out that at least to me it appears to be a bug. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/22864) into the glassfish repo:

Following the stack trace the `name` passed by [StandardContext.java](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/blob/master/appserver/web/web-core/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContext.java) at line 7382 is null

```
    // Construct a RequestDispatcher to process this request
    return new ApplicationDispatcher
        (wrapper, mappingForDispatch, uriCC.toString(), wrapperPath, pathInfo,
         queryString, null);
```

Therefore the calls to the methods results in null pointer exception, because the log level is FINE in production (because is not production yet) if you look at [ApplicationDispatcher.java](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/blob/master/appserver/web/web-core/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationDispatcher.java) line

```
    if (log.isLoggable(Level.FINE))
        log.log(Level.FINE, "servletPath= " + neutralizeForLog(this.servletPath) + ", pathInfo= "
                + neutralizeForLog(this.pathInfo) + ", queryString= " + neutralizeForLog(queryString) + ", name= "
                + neutralizeForLog(this.name));
```

And eventually the `neutralizeForLog` fails, because message is in fact null.